# Android Retrofit: How to only take few data from List and show it in alertdialog list?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

i actually stuck here. I use retrofit, i already made the POJO class CategoryResponse.class & CategoryData.class here is my data in JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Category Report Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "id_category": 1,
            "category_name": "Mother Nature POWER",
            "created_at": "2021-09-29T21:25:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-29T21:25:07.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id_category": 2,
            "category_name": "Terrorisme",
            "created_at": "2021-09-29T21:25:20.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-29T21:25:20.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my "api.interface" to get the data with token bearer:

```
 @GET("mobile/category")
    Call<CategoryResponse> getCategoryList(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

And here is how i call it in Activity class:

```
Call<CategoryResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .getCategoryList(rtoken);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Response<CategoryResponse> response) {

                CategoryResponse categoryResponse = response.body();
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<CategoryData> kategoriList = categoryResponse.getData();
                    
                     

                     -------- HERE IS WHERE I STUCK---------



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddReportActivity.this, "Something is wrong i can feel it..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

My problem is how to get only id_category + category_name, and put it inside alertdialog list, to make a simple dynamic list inside onResponse? bcuz i just want to save the id and/or the name after clicked the name on the alerdialog list. The admin just need to edit the list from the server.

*Update, here is my POJO CategoryData.clas:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CategoryData {

    @SerializedName("category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;

    @SerializedName("id_category")
    private int idCategory;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    public void setCategoryName (String categoryName){
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryName(){
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt){
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt(){
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setIdCategory(int idCategory){
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
    }

    public int getIdCategory(){
        return idCategory;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt){
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt(){
        return createdAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class with these two fields and map a list of full objects to list of object with two fields

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii like a new java class?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: remove idCategory and categoryName from CategoryData, if you are making base class with these params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()){
                List<CategoryData> kategoriList = categoryResponse.getData();
                 for(int i=0;i<kategoriList.size();i++)
               {
               // assuming that you have defined categoryID and categoryname in your pojo class. Change it accordingly 
                 String categotyID = kategoriList.get(i).getCategoryID();
                 String categoryName = kategoriList.get(i).getCategoryName();

             }
                 

                



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddReportActivity.this, "Something is wrong i can feel it..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: i'll definietly try it

Comment: thank you, im using this to make spinner adapter instead, and it's super useful, i just need to get the id with String.valueOf bcuz it's int, and make private list<string> for each and store id again in String variable again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

You can make `class BaseCategoryData` with only two parameters (Id and name) here is the example:

```
class BaseCategoryData{

   // here two fields category id and name;

}

class CategoryData extends BaseCategoryData{

   // here remaining fields

}
```

And at the time of fetching:

```
 List<BaseCategoryData> kategoriList = (List<BaseCategoryData>) categoryResponse.getData();
```

If it works, then here we uses the **inheritance** logic using extends and **downcasting** the list from response will give us correct list you want.

Comment: ahh, so instead of put my CategoryData.class inside the List<>, i put a new class named BaseCategoryData inside the List<>. So what should i put inside BaseCategoryData, setter & getter?

Comment: ya, if list is downcast to base class then you have 2 variables only on that base class, I am just trying to explain logic so I didn't write getter setter code for you, so sorry for that.

Comment: thank you so much tho, but i already created POJO class for all the data in category as CategoryData.class, can i use that instead?

Comment: But, what is the problem if you make a base class of CategoryData??

Comment: i mean, it kinda feel like i can use it instead of creating the new one with the same function

Comment: If you want as your requirement "bcuz i just want to save the id and/or the name" that's why i am suggesting you to use required field on base class and additional field on child class, so its easy to downcast, otherwise if you want to use same class then, this answer is not suitable for you.

Comment: alright i will try it, so i make class basecategorydata and class categorydata extends basecategorydata all inside basecategory.class? or i edited my CategoryData into ```CategoryData extends BaseCategoryData``` and then make BaseCategoryData.class

Comment: Is this working now??

Comment: it seems not working, the CategoryData.class is public void, i extends it with basecategorydata, it want me to change void for BaseCategoryData, after i changed it, it want me to delete it.

Comment: Can you share your code of CategoryData class,